# Python, MQTT broker, publish message

Tags: python, mqtt, publish-subscribe

I have configured MQTT Broker, receiving published messages from another piece of code (not written or accessible by me). I added another topic to the broker configuration and am now trying to publish data to this new topic from a piece of python code. I get the feedback that the message is published by the callback function, but no actual data is received.

Is there anything I am missing?

I am using the following code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

#=========================================================================  
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc) :
    print "on_connect()"

#=========================================================================
def on_publish(client, userdata, mid) :
    print "on_publish()"

#=========================================================================
def send() :
    mqttc = mqtt.Client()
    mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
    mqttc.on_publish = on_publish

    #host      = "localhost"
    host      = "127.0.0.1"
    port      = 1883
    keepalive = 60

    print "\nConnect to '%s', port '%s', keepalive '%s'" % (host, port, keepalive)
    mqttc.connect(host=host, port=port, keepalive=keepalive)

    time.sleep(3)        
    mqttc.loop_start()    
    time.sleep(3)

    topic = "data/MY/TOPIC"
    msg = "MY_MESSAGE"

    print "Publish to '%s' msg '%s'" % (topic, msg)
    mqttc.publish(topic, msg, qos=2)

    time.sleep(3)   
    mqttc.loop_stop()
# end send()

#=========================================================================
if __name__ == "__main__":
    send()
# end if
```

Getting the stdout

```
Connect to '127.0.0.1', port '1883', keepalive '60'
on_connect()
Publish to 'data/MY/TOPIC' msg 'MY MESSAGE'
on_publish()
```

I am not sure if the loop() functions are necessary, but if I do not embed the publishing in the loop_start() and loop_stop(), I do not get a on_connect callback.

Comment: The code you have posted there, while not great, does actually work fine for me. (Given that the connection is only alive for 9 seconds max, there is no need to set the keepalive)

Comment: So you say this code works, an the error must be on the configuration side of the broker?

Comment: What are you using to test? I just used mosquitto_sub -v -t '#' to see if anything showed up. It could be the ACL on the broker not allowing you to publish to that topic

Comment: Something that might help is using the on_log callback which will provide you with more useful feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The loop functions are necessary as these are where all the network traffic is processed.

Manually setting up a connection to the broker to just send a single message like this is not a good idea, it would be better to start the client, leave it running (by calling `loop_start()` and not calling `loop_stop()`) in the background and then just call the publish method on the `mqttc` client object.

If you don't want to keep a instance of the client running then you should use the single message publish helper method provided by the paho python library (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt/1.1#single):

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

publish.single("paho/test/single", "payload", hostname="iot.eclipse.org")
```

Comment: I tried `publish.single(topic=topic, payload=msg, qos=2, hostname=host, port=port, keepalive=keepalive)`, but the data is still not received by the broker. Also this function does not return anything to check for a successful publishing!?